# User access control in sidebar archive and categorires

Tags: user-access

Could someone please help me solve my problem which is: I want content restrictions based on user roles and a sidebar category based on user roles. I have three type of user roles: Beginner, Intermediate and Advanced.

Beginner Role: can read only self blog
Intermediate Role: can read self and beginner blog
Advanced Role: full read access to all levels of the blog

The same case is with sidebar archives and categories if user is logged in. With beginner role (like demo/demo), user could only view beginner member area and limited sidebar categories and archives.

case 2: if user is logged in with intermediate role (inter/inter), user could view intermediate area and would be able to see beginner, self category and archives.

case 3: advanaced user login with (adv/adv) could view advanced member area and would be able to see all level categories.

please help me

Answer (score 1):

The [Members Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) would allow you to define a user role then you could use the [widget logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) plugin to control the sidebar. Something like `current user can('new_role')` Show sidebar

Answer (score 0):

I believe [role-scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) would fit your needs well.

> Role Scoper is a comprehensive access control solution, giving you
>   CMS-like control of reading and editing permissions. Assign
>   restrictions and roles to specific pages, posts or categories.

With this, users would automatically see only menu items that are within the scope of their roles, so it answers both your questions.

Comment: hii @pootzko but its not full fill my requirement because when beginner level user login he have access to see all archive and categorizes displaying in sidebar what i want to restrict user level to see only  the category based on user role like beginner only see own category and archive , intermediate self n beginner and advance all